# Number of List Item Print Preview Next Line

Tags: c#

I want to number of array of list item, print next line in Print preview.
The problem is: all list item overwrite.

```
p.PrintPage += delegate(object sender1, PrintPageEventArgs e1)
                 {

                     foreach (CheckBox linkcheck in panel1.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
                     {
                         list = new List<string>();
                         if (linkcheck.Checked == true)
                         {
                                 list.Add(linkcheck.Text );
                                 for(int k=0;k<list.Count;k++)
                                 {
                                     SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(fontDialog1.Color);
                                     e1.Graphics.DrawString("Name , " + list[k]+"\n\r", fontDialog1.Font, brush, 90, 400);

                                 }
                         }

                 };
```

Comment: Please try to be more clear with what your problem is

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, the previous values disappear from the list, move the code `list = new List<string>();` to before the foreach

Comment: +1: A pretty fair assumption given the state of the question

Comment: Sorry, Not change Same Problem,

Comment: All array of list item , overwritten...

Comment: Could you please explain your problem better then

Comment: I take it you mean the List<string> list is overwritten, when and with what is it overwritten?

Comment: when i click, show  printpreview button. all the inside of listitem (i.e string) , over write. while preview report generate.....